# « Général » ou « générique » : comment choisir ?

Tags: sens, usage, choix-de-mot

J'ai du mal à savoir quand utiliser « général » ou « générique ». Quelqu'un a-t-il des moyens mnémotechniques, ou saurait-il présenter une sorte d'arbre de décision à ce propos ?

Par exemple, dans « la méthode présentée sur cet exemple est en fait très générale » — il me semble qu'ici, « générique » pourrait convenir (dans son sens d'antonyme de « spécifique »). Est-ce le cas ?

Answer (score 7):

Il me semble que *générique* est plus précis que *général*, mais *générique* — bien que réservé à quelques domaines de spécialité — m'a tout l'air de pouvoir remplacer *général* à chaque fois qu'il est employé comme adjectif.

La différence est peut-être seulement qu'on peut dire *`en général`*.

Typiquement, et pour rester, je pense, dans le champ mathématique, j'appelerai ***générique*** quelque chose qui peut être **paramétrisé**, même avec les mains, et ***général*** quelque chose qui s'applique largement, mais dans un sens **plus flou**. Il me semble que si on a une solution *générique*, alors on doit pouvoir trouver un *générateur* de solutions particulières, ce que ne garantit pas une solution *générale*.

---

Au premier abord, dans ton exemple, oui, j'aurais dit que *générique* convenait, mais en y réfléchissant, ça dépend peut-être de ce qu'est exactement la méthode. D'un autre côté, en essayant de trouver un exemple, soit il vaut mieux reformuler avec *en général*, soit on peut remplacer *général* par *générique*.

> La méthode générale pour traiter un problème consiste à essayer de le simplifier avant de le résoudre.

Mais je ne trompe personne, et j'ai dans l'idée qu'il vaudrait mieux dire :

> En général, il faut simplifier les problèmes avant de les résoudre.

Comment: Dans le jargon mathématique, *générique* a un sens bien particulier et veut dire que la propriété en question est une propriété typique des membres de la classe en question (cette phrase ambigüe a une définition précise mais technique). Par exemple, génériquement, trois points dans le plan ne sont pas sur une même droite.

Comment: Soit, je ne connaissais pas. (Mais est-ce même répandu à *toutes* les maths, et par exemple, qu'est-ce qu'une classe ? (En fait je veux bien voir la définition technique :)) Je n'ai tout de même pas l'impression que ça soit ce que demande F'x.

Comment: Je suis entièrement d'accord que la définition mathématique n'est pas pertinente... :-) Wikipedia donne une définition un peu restrictive en français http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classe_de_Baire . L'article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_property est plus détaillé, mais en anglais. Je suis spécialiste en topologie/géométrie et donc je ne suis pas qualifié pour parler de toutes les maths. Si tu veux en discuter plus, n'hésite pas à me contacter par mail. Tu peux trouver mon adresse sur ma page web.

Answer (score 4):

Dans les acceptions considérées, *générique*, c'est propre à un *genre*, une classe caractérisée par des traits communs, tandis que *général*, c'est ce qui s'applique à tous. Pour moi, on va donc utiliser *générique* quand l'applicabilité est vaste mais conditionnée par des propriétés.

Answer (score 3):

Parmi les définitions du Robert :

**Générique** (didactique) qui appartient à la compréhension logique du genre (opposé à spécifique) ; *caractère générique*, qui désigne un genre entier
... (et aussi : *Médicament générique* dont le brevet est tombé dans le domaine public, et aussi *générique* d'un film)

**Général** : qui s'applique , se réfère à un ensemble de cas ou d'individus (opposé à particulier)

Il semble qu'il s'agisse de deux mouvements de la pensée opposé lorsqu'elle observe:

- on découvre quelque chose, on en cherche la *genèse*, ce qui constitue sa particularité et que l'on veut ensuite expliquer pour partager ses connaissances [de génération en génération] (ce qui explique la signification *didactique* retenue dans Le Robert), 
  Pour  *générique* il s'agit donc d'un  mouvement vers le centre de ce qui est observé.
  C'est  la perception du locuteur qui désire expliquer la constitution, les aspects particuliers souvent masqués d'un sujet ou d'un objet.
- on observe un ensemble et on cherche les points communs.
  Il s'agit donc de situer un sujet observé parmi ses semblables.
  C'est la discrimination du locuteur, qui envisage des règles ou des lois d'un ensemble.

Dans le cadre d'une formation, d'un exposé, si *générique* vous vient à l'esprit pour préciser votre discours, pourquoi pas, surtout si c'est 'logique'.
Dans le cadre d'une explication, d'une discussion, d'un échange de points de vue ou les rapprochements et différentiation entre divers groupes sont observés, *général* devrait convenir, surtout si l'intuition (si l'on se réfère à la *doxa*) est prédominante
Bien sûr il existe beaucoup de situation intermédiaires, avec des interférences possibles où l'on pourrait ergoter indéfiniment.
Pour ma part, j'emploie rarement *générique*, qu'inconsciemment je rattache à gène, origine ou à quelque chose de *précis* ; *général* est rattaché à 'en général', soit quelque chose de *vague*.